# Let $p, q \in k[x_1,...,x_n]$ with no common divisor. Must there exist $a, b \in k$ so $ap + bq$ is irreducible?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field and let $p, q$ be polynomials in $k[x_1,...,x_n]$ with no common divisor, $n > 1$. Must there exist $a, b \in k$ so $ap + bq$ is irreducible? This question occurred to me while working through an exercise in Hartshorne. I do not feel I have the commutative algebra/number theory background to hazard a proof attempt. Can anyone please supply a proof, or direct me to a reference? I am also interested in the case where $p$ and $q$ are homogeneous of the same degree, or when $k = \mathbb{C}$, if that is easier. Assuming this is true for algebraically closed $k$, I would also be curious of its validity or failure over more general classes of fields. Thanks.

Edit: I asked [a revised version of this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4435938/let-p-q-in-kx-1-x-n-with-no-common-divisor-n-ge-3-and-a-nontrivia) which attempts to exclude the counterexamples found by Nicolás Vilches.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $p=x^2$ and $q=y^2$ inside $k[x, y]$. Note that
$$ ap+bq=a(x^2+b/a \cdot y^2)=a(x-\lambda y)(x+\lambda y) $$
where $\lambda^2=-b/a$. (This assumes $a\neq 0$, but this is not a problem.)

This idea should work for any $p, q \in k[x, y]$ homogeneous of the same degree, as we use that any homogeneous polynomial in $k[x, y]$ splits as a product of linear factors. In particular, you can take $p=x^2-y^2$, $q=x^2-2y^2$, if you don't want $p$ and $q$ to have repeated factors.

Comment: Ah, good answer. Thank you. I did not realize that every homogeneous polynomial in two variables splits (of course now this seems clear from the algebraic closedness of $k$, simply plugging in $1$ for one of the variables and factorizing). I may ask the question again for $n \ge 3$, where each of the $n$ indeterminates occurs in $p$. Unless you see an easy counterexample in this case?

Comment: It is not obvious how to avoid this: we can e.g. take $(x-y-z)^2, y^2$, which are "the same polynomials up to a linear change of variables".

Comment: Again, good point. Perhaps the interesting condition on $p$ should be some form of "there is no change of variables such that $p$ is a polynomial in less than $n$ variables."

Comment: Hi @NicolásVilches, this is unrelated to your answer, hence I would be deleting this comment soonest. Please could you help out with this question https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4435979/585488