# Let $p, q \in k[x_1,...,x_n]$ with no common divisor, $n\ge3$ (and a nontriviality condition). Must $\exists a, b \in k$ so $ap + bq$ is irreducible?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field and let $p, q$ be polynomials in $A = k[x_1,...,x_n]$ with no common divisor, $n \ge 3$. Additionally, we impose a nontriviality condition: suppose $p$ has at least $n$ distinct irreducible divisors, and for each indeterminate $x_1,...,x_n$, at least one of the monomials in $p$ is divisible by that indeterminate. Must there exist $a, b \in k$ so $ap + bq$ is irreducible?

[I previously asked this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4435775/let-p-q-in-kx-1-x-n-with-no-common-divisor-must-there-exist-a-b-in) for $n \ge 2$, without the nontriviality condition. Nicolás Vilches showed that under those weaker assumptions, there are simple counterexamples in $n = 2$ which induce counterexamples in all higher $n$. I hope the nontriviality condition is not too contrived to viably work with. I am particularly interested in the case $n = 3$.

Comment: This is false in positive characteristics. For example, take $p=(x_1x_2\cdots x_n)^l$ and $q=(x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_n)^l$ where $l$ is the characteristic.